# How to extract the auth bearer token for the given url using python?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, python-requests, ui-automation, build-automation

Scenario: I'm trying to automate an API with get request.

It requires Auth bearer token. However, the token keeps changing.

Is there a way to fetch the Auth bearer token dynamically during the runtime in python?

Please help...

Comment: Not sure what API you're using, but here's an example using the Twitter API. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/bearer-tokens. You can convert the curl command you use to obtain your bearer token into a Python request to automate your workflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.